# Use AutoMapper to map a string array to an object

Tags: c#, csv, automapper, textfieldparser

I am using `TextFieldParser` to parse a CSV file to import into a database using `EntityFramework`.

`TextFieldParser` returns each line of the CSV file as a `string[]`. In order to save the objects, I need to build an object from each line. Is there any way to do this using `AutoMapper`?

My object structure is like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And my CSV lines are in the following format:

> FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Address,PhoneNumber

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done fairly easily in `AutoMapper` by doing something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string[], Person>()
    .ForMember(p => p.FirstName, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s[0]))
    .ForMember(p => p.MiddleName, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s[1]))
    .ForMember(p => p.LastName, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s[2]))
    .ForMember(p => p.Address, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s[3]))
    .ForMember(p => p.PhoneNumber, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s[4]));
```

Keep in mind that this mapping is dependent on the order of the values in the CSV file.